# Unfair Candy Distribution

Tags: java, class, logic

I am completing an assignment and am having a hard time figuring out the logic need to make the program work. I do not want a direct answer but could someone point me in the right direction?

Assignment:
Define a class named UnfairCandyDistributor.  An UnfairCandyDistributor object represents a mean big brother who is going to divide a set of candies between himself and his hungry little brother.  This will be done unfairly: for every candy given to the sibling, the big brother takes for himself a number of additional candies equal to the younger sibling's total.  Each UnfairCandyDistributor object should have the same method:
public void nextCandy()
Each time nextCandy is called, the method prints a message about who gets a candy.  Each call to nextCandy produces a single line of output.  This time the output is the following:

```
public class TestCandy2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UnfairCandyDistributor mean = new UnfairCandyDistributor();
        mean.nextCandy();        // 1 for you.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 1 for me.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 2 for you.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 1 for me.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 2 for me.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 3 for you.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 1 for me.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 2 for me.
        mean.nextCandy();        // 3 for me.
```

Here The class I have made so far:

```
public class UnfairCandyDistributor {

    private int you;
    private int me;
    private int extra;


    public void nextCandy()
    {

        if (you != me || extra != you - 1)
        {
            me++;
            System.out.println(me + " for me");
        }
        else
        {
                 you++;
                 System.out.println(you + " for you");
            extra = 0;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what's the question? "Having a hard time" is extremely fuzzy, try to explain where you got stuck. That will not only help us point you in the right direction, but quite often, while thinking about the problem and how to express it, the problem will become clearer as well.

Comment: _could someone point point me in the right direction_ is not a problem statement. Please take the tour and read the help center to understand what questions are appropriate on Stack Overflow. Voting to put on hold as unclear.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1393766)

Comment: I am having a hard time determining the logic for the class, how should I go about setting up the logic.  I can not get the program to alternate between assigning candy between "you" and "me" as described

Comment: In addition to the above comments, please check how to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example, which is the best way to ask questions on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add a boolean variable that tells you who to dole out candy to?

```
public class UnfairCandyDistributor {

    private int you = 0;
    private int me = 0;
    private boolean candyToMe = false;

    public void nextCandy()
    {
        if (candyToMe)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<you; i++) {
                 System.out.println("one for me");
                 me++;
        }
        else
        {
                 System.out.println("one for you");
                 you++;
        }
        candyToMe = !candyToMe;
    } 
}
```

or

```
public class UnfairCandyDistributor {

    private int you = 0;
    private int me = 0;
    private boolean candyToMe = false;

    public void nextCandy()
    {
        if (candyToMe)
        {
                 System.out.println(you + " for me");
                 me += you;
        }
        else
        {
                 System.out.println("1 for you");
                 you++;
        }
        candyToMe = !candyToMe;
    } 
}
```

..depending on whether you want the candies doled out one at a time or in hand-fulls where appropriate.